# i am not able to overlay the boxes using z-index

Tags: html, css

I have tried my best to solve the issue but it's not working. I want to make a gradient border on my website for a slideshow (similar to the one on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EAtn4B-76g&t=11s)). I used (`:before`) pseudo selector here is my `HTML` code:

```css
* {
  color: white;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #060c21;
}


/* NavBar Starts */

#mainnav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 98%;
  position: static;
}

.items>a {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.items {
  margin: 0 5vw 0 5vw;
  padding: 1vw;
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.items>a:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 255, 242);
}


/* NavBar Ends */


/* Content Starts */

.slide-box {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 75vh;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 2% auto;
}

.slide-box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  background: white;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Practice</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@531&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif; -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Vaishnavi.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div id="mainnav">
      <div class="items">
        <a href="Vaishnavi.html">Home</a>
      </div>

      <div class="items">
        <a href="">About US</a>
      </div>

      <div class="items">
        <a href="">Creations</a>
      </div>

      <div class="items">
        <a href="">Help</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="slide-box">
    <h1>This is glowing box</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo voluptatibus et quasi illum inventore rem excepturi quam tenetur eius est, minima aliquam repellendus deleniti modi laudantium similique iste ipsum? Ad!
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please tell me the mistake I am making and why my `z-index` is not working correctly. In my view, I have written the code correctly.

Comment: can you please provide sandbox or fiddle link ?

Comment: And can you please explain a bit more what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something that you are looking for?

You can see that I recreated the example based on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EAtn4B-76g&t=11s) that you have provided.

```css
* {
  color: white;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #060c21;
}


/* NavBar Starts */

#mainnav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 98%;
  position: static;
}

.items>a {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.items {
  margin: 0 5vw 0 5vw;
  padding: 1vw;
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.items>a:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 255, 242);
}


/* NavBar Ends */


/* Content Starts */

.slide-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 2% auto;
  height: 75vh;
  width: 95%;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000, #262626);
}
.slide-box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fb0094, #0000ff, #00ff00, #ffff00, #ff0000, #fb0094, #0000ff, #00ff00, #ffff00, #ff0000);
  background-size: 400%;
  width: calc(100% + 4px);
  height: calc(100% + 4px);
  z-index: -1;
  animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 400% 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Practice</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@531&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif; -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Vaishnavi.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div id="mainnav">
        <div class="items">
          <a href="Vaishnavi.html">Home</a>
        </div>

        <div class="items">
          <a href="">About US</a>
        </div>

        <div class="items">
          <a href="">Creations</a>
        </div>

        <div class="items">
          <a href="">Help</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="slide-box">
      <h1>This is glowing box</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo voluptatibus et quasi illum inventore rem excepturi quam tenetur eius est, minima aliquam repellendus deleniti modi laudantium similique iste ipsum? Ad!
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What you were missing in your code to see the text was the line below:

```
.slide-box {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000, #262626);
}
```

---

The `z-index` worked just fine but because your background color was white and also the text color was white, you could not see the text.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Jakub A Suplicki but i wanted to have a gradient box- shadow with animation which changes its color in respect of time so i referred to [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EAtn4B-76g&t=11s) and you can see that i have done the same , that he had done but for him the z-index works and for me its not . then i tried to do that again but not in my code so i wrote the same code like him but sill i did't work .

Comment: I edited my answer based on the video and also your code, please have a look. You can also add `.slide-box:after {filter: blur(20px);}` if you wanted to achieve the blur effect.

Comment: Thank you sooo much dude , can use also tell me why you used this:-.slide-box:before, .slide-box:after  And what is ment by (height: calc(100% + 4px);)  calc in this code

Comment: `:after` and `:before` are pseudo-elements - children of the selected element, you can read more about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after They are very useful when it comes to styling, as they can be just empty blocks that you add styles to (a shortcut from creating an actual children elements).

We use `calc(100% + 4px);` because these elements are behind the parent element (`z-index: -1`) so to make them visible we need to first move them to the left and top (`-2px`) and then add extra (`2px+2px (4px)`) to 100% of height and width - make them visible again.

Comment: If you do not want the blur effect on `:after` then you can remove `.slide-box:after`. I removed it from my answer. Now we use only one pseudo-element - `:before`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code how you can achieve gradient border(code is copied from css-tricks). For more please visit [here](https://css-tricks.com/gradient-borders-in-css/)

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: #222;
}

.module-border-wrap {
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, purple);
  padding: 3px;
}

.module {
  background: #222;
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="module-border-wrap">
  <div class="module">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero pariatur corporis quaerat voluptatum eos tempora temporibus nisi voluptates sed, exercitationem sequi dolore culpa incidunt accusamus, quasi unde reprehenderit ea molestias.
  </div>
  
</div>
```